# LoadRunner - Why my parameters are showing blank?

Tags: parameters, automated-tests, performance-testing, coded-ui-tests, loadrunner

I created a test script where Launch URL will be parameterized.
I created a .dat parameter file With list of URLs.

When I Simulate the parameters to test the results it shows blank.

As shown in screenshot.
[image]

When I use other data as in Customer name etc then the simulation shows correct. Just for these URLs it shows blank and I am assuming it runs blanks too.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a bug. Fixed in version 12.15
However, workaround was to scroll at the bottom of visible row and click. It shows remaining ones.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've unearthed a real bug in VuGen. We're going to fix it, in the meantime my only suggestion is to create two columns - one with shorter values (e.g. without GUID's) just for simulation, and another with the real values for the real parameterization (you'll need to play with the "Select column" setting a bit).

Comment: Yea.. seems like a bug. I somehow couldn't make columns to work.

Comment: Turns out values don't show when they're longer than 100 characters. We're fixing it in the coming release. Thanks for discovering it!